# How to validate use the remote or local database with mvvm android

Tags: android, database, validation, mvvm

I try to do if I do not have an internet connection, I use the local database, if I have access to the internet, I use the remote database and I save the data obtained in the local database, I try to validate verifying that they are active wi-fi or data in the cell phone, but you can not really determine if I have an internet connection, what can I do? If someone has an example or a repository, it would be great, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to determine availability of internet.

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
try {
    final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
    return !address.equals(""); // if we find the address that means internet is working
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // Log error
}
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the following link to determine whether the internet is available or not:

[Detect whether there is an Internet connection available on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use BoundaryCallback

When local storage is a cache of network data, it's common to set up a streaming pipeline: Network data is paged into the database, database is paged into UI.

[BoundaryCallback](http:////https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.BoundaryCallback)